# "An edit has been made to this post" bar has same text color and bg color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

When there's a change made to a question or answer that you're viewing, a handy bar pops up saying so, with a link to refresh the page to show the updated content.  On meta, this bar has the text color and background color the same, so it appears to just be a strange grey bar.  Here's a picture:
[image: Screenshot of grey bar]

Comment: [Yet another…](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/tag-merge-results-are-eaeaea-on-eaeaea-on-meta)

Comment: Ditto for the “N questions with new activity” bar on the main page and `/questions` page.

Comment: I want to say that an unread changed favorited question in the Favorites tab of the user profile appears the same way. I only have one favorite there right now and I've visited it since it changed; so while it is still hard to read, it is presently not invisible like the other examples so I can't screenshot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This and the "N questions with new activity" bars will be fixed in the next build, > rev 2012.5.4.2454.